# TextView issues after migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewbinding

I recently migrate binding method from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding. I have AutofitTextView (by grantland) in my fragment and I set some text to the textview. After I started the activity and attached the fragment, the app crash. The error said

***java.lang.ClassCastExceptioni: androidx.appcompt.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView***

So, I decided to change from AutoFitTextView to AppCompatTextView but I face another issue. I cannot build the app because there is an error

***Unresolve reference: setText***

I tried various settext methods but none of them works. It seems that the TextView is seen as a View so it does not have a setText method.

========

Config details

- Android Studio 4.1.2
- buildToolsVersion 28.0.3
- jvmTarget 1.8
- com.android.databinding:compiler 3.1.4
- androidx.appcommpat:appcompat:1.2.0

==========

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    .... >
    <LinearLayout
        .... >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/myTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is textview" />
            ....
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Set text

> FragmentMainBinding.myTextView.text = "The new text"

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: @Eyosiyas Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause!! It's my mistake. I have 2 layouts with the same name, one for portrait and another one for landscape. I migrate the views in portrait layout but not in landscape layout so when binding class is generated, it generate the two different TextViews as View and View does not have "text" attribute. That's what the error said.

Comment: mine was fullsensor than I set it to portrait and it worked too

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would have taken me quite some time to realise!

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.

```
val binder =  FragmentMainBinding.bind(View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.fragment_main, null))

binder.myTextView.text = "The new text"
```

Comment: Provide the entire FragmentMain layout and Kotlin code.

Answer (score 0):

So if that is your entire xml for `fragment_main.xml`, you need to wrap all of it with `<layout>` tag. That's the only way the compiler knows to build the binding classes.

```
<layout
  ...>
    <FrameLayout
    .... >
    <LinearLayout
        .... >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/myTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is textview" />
            ....
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I think this may not the solution. Other layouts does not have <layout> tag and it works normally.